# JAXL based chat client. Need help connecting to Gtalk or other server to test

Tags: php, xmpp, google-talk

I wish to send a message to XMPP based chat servers using php. 
I am using JAXL, which seems the best (of limited) options for pure PHP server based chat.

However, I have yet to establish any connect, let alone send a message.
I am having a hard time working out if the problem is my code, my server (which is shared server, but has Cpanel, and a very helpfull host), or my settings.

The code I am using to try to connect  to GTalk is;

```
$client = new JAXL(array(
  'jid' => 'name@gmail.com',
  'pass' =>  'password',
  'host'=> 'talk.google.com',
  'port'=> 5222,
  'domain'=> 'gmail.com', //unsure if this is the right setting.
  'force_tls' => true,
  'auth_type' => @$argv[3] ? $argv[3] : 'PLAIN',
      ));


//
// required XEP's
//
$client->require_xep(array(
'0199'  // XMPP Ping
));

//
// add necessary event callbacks here
//

$client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
global $client;
_info("got on_auth_success cb, jid ".$client->full_jid->to_string());

// fetch roster list
$client->get_roster();

// fetch vcard
$client->get_vcard();

// set status
$client->set_status("available!", "dnd", 10);
});
$client->add_cb('on_connect_error', function() {
echo 'Connect Error';
});
$client->add_cb('on_auth_failure', function() {
echo 'Auth Error';
});
$client->add_cb('on_auth_success', function() {
global $client;
echo 'connected';
$client->send_chat_msg('test2@domain.com', 'webtest');
$client->shutdown();
}); 

//
// finally start configured xmpp stream
//

$client->start(array(
'--with-debug-shell' => true,
'--with-unix-sock' => true
));
echo "done\n";
```

Triggering the php (from a browser) then results in the server getting stuck. (no "done" message, just constant loading till a timeout from the browser)

The server logs show;

```
 strict mode enabled, adding exception handlers. Set 'strict'=>TRUE inside JAXL config to disable this[0m
 error handler called with 8, Undefined index: priv_dir,
```

And then lots of;

```
 unable to connect tcp://talk.google.com:5222 with error no: 110, error str: Connection timed out
```

So I would appreciate help with any of the following;

- Any specific problems with my code
- Any issues with the gtalk connection settings at the start
- Alternative recommendations to investigate this issue.
- Or any general advice from people that have successfully used JAXL.

Thanks,
Thomas Wrobel

Comment: I need the same thing, did you solve it?

Comment: No :(
Very little help on this subject anywhere either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem might be TCP port is closed for your hosting , try to open it with your hosting first, also try to run your code locally to see if it's work fine .

Some people reported the issue was fixed by override method connect from file XMLStream.php by this one

```
  /**
 * Connect to XMPP Host
 *
 * @param integer $timeout
 * @param boolean $persistent
 * @param boolean $sendinit
 */
public function connect($timeout = 30, $persistent = false, $sendinit = true) {
    $this->sent_disconnect = false;
    $starttime = time();

    do {
        $this->disconnected = false;
        $this->sent_disconnect = false;
        if($persistent) {
            $conflag = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT;
        } else {
            $conflag = STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT;
        }
        $conntype = 'tcp';
        if($this->use_ssl) $conntype = 'ssl';
        $this->log->log("Connecting to $conntype://{$this->host}:{$this->port}");
        try {
            $this->socket = @stream_socket_client("$conntype://{$this->host}:{$this->port}", $errno, $errstr, $timeout, $conflag);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new XMPPHP_Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
        if(!$this->socket) {
            $this->log->log("Could not connect.",  XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_ERROR);
            $this->disconnected = true;
            # Take it easy for a few seconds
            sleep(min($timeout, 5));
        }
    } while (!$this->socket/* && (time() - $starttime) < $timeout*/);

    if ($this->socket) {
        stream_set_blocking($this->socket, 0);
        if($sendinit) $this->send($this->stream_start);
    } else {
        throw new XMPPHP_Exception("Could not connect before timeout.");
    }
}
```